# Mutex for private object - global vs attribute

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, mutex

I have a class Processor that can be notified of objects.
The notified objects are eventually processed in a separate thread.

Since the queue is shared between different threads, it needs a mutex `q_mutex` to prevent erroneous behavior.

```
class Processor {
    std::queue<int> q;
    void q_processing_thread();    // while true loop - uses the mutex
public:
    void notify(int);  // pushes int to q - uses the mutex
    bool isEmpty() const;     // checks if the queue is empty  - uses the mutex
};
```

**The question:**

Should the mutex be an attribute of Processor or a global variable ?

Conceptually,

- `isEmpty` should be `const` since it shouldn't be altering the object. However that prevents it from 
  locking the mutex.
- the mutex has no meaning outside the class since the queue is a private attribute of Processor.

Comment: Make the mutex `mutable`.  That allows you to change it in a `const` method.

Answer (score 3):

The mutex should be part of the class.

You can specify it as [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/mutable) to make it usable in `const` methods.

```
Class Processor {
    std::queue<int> q;
    mutable std::mutex q_mutex;
    . . .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are generally frowned upon.

Since C++ does not have an owning mutex it is best to just have it be a member attribute

mutable allows it to be mutated even if your `this` is const

```cpp
class Processor {
    std::queue<int> q;
    mutable std::mutex mtx;
    void q_processing_thread();    // while true loop - uses the mutex
public:
    void notify(int);  // pushes int to q - uses the mutex
    bool isEmpty() const;     // checks if the queue is empty  - uses the mutex
};
```

Lock as soon as you need the mutex, preferably through std::lock_guard or scoped_lock.

Do not keep it locked any more time than nessecary as this can cause performance issues

Answer (score 0):

A mutex should be declared with the same scope and extent as the data that it protects.  The only data in your example, is the member variable `q`. So, *assuming* that `q` is what you want to protect, then a mutex that is intended to protect `q` probably should be a member of the same class.